# django admin not showing some css and form features

Tags: css, django, django-admin

I copied my django (v1.10) source code to my Apache server, and executed the `python manage.py collectstatic`, it copied 420 files to `/var/www/sitename/mainwork/static`. 
The website's css itself works fine, but the admin does not show some features!

[image: like this snapshot].

It also does not show some links of the forms: (the first snapshot is the way it is supposed to be)
the way it supposed to be:

[image: preview from the local 127.0.0.1]

the way it is, with missing link:

[image: preview from mysite.com]

what is causing this problem?

Thanks in advance. (if any code is required just tell me to add here)

**Edit1:** 
This is the console errors related to the third snapshot:
[image]

Comment: Did you restart the server and try to empty your browser cache?

Comment: @voodoo-burger:  yes I did these things, didn't work.

Comment: Do you get any JS errors in the console?

Comment: @PatrickBeeson yeah, I added the errors to the question

Comment: @user3017468 I don't see that you have...

Comment: @PatrickBeeson sorry about that. It is added now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were different versions of django installed on the server (django 1.8 on apt-get and 1.10 on virtualenv!). and I think it caused a conflict on `python manage.py collectstatic`. (The website was running with django 1.10, but the admin's static files were from 1.8)

I removed the django 1.8, deleted the `static/admin folder`, and executed the `collectstatic` again. and the problem is resolved.